# How to integrate AdMob with Unity iOS project?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I have faced a problem where my game works fine but when I am trying to make it work with `AdMob`, it gives me error in Xcode.

The error is

ld: framework not found GoogleMobileAds 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)

But my point is that I have imported the `GoogleMobileAds` framework and all the other frameworks what google developer site said, but it still doesn't work.

[image: screenshot 1]

and this:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: It would help a lot of if you add your code and steps that you did to produce the error.

Comment: I tried importing the framework and tried to add it to search paths, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode select your Target, go to Build Settings, search for *Search Paths*.

It should give you 3 lists of directories - Header Search Paths, Framework Search Paths and Libary Search paths. In Framework Search Paths Make sure non of the directories have quotation marks "like this" and make sure the directory of your GoogleMobileAds.framework is listed. If not than add it.

If there is no GoogleMobileAds.framework file in your entire project than try to look with Finder (it may still be in the project repository but not linked to the project). If you can't find it than just copy it from Unity project Assets/Plugins/iOS/GoogleStuffDirectoryOrSomething/GoogleMobileAds.framework and paste it in Xcode project using Finder, then from Finder manually drag and drop it in Xcode so that project gets the reference to that file.

Build.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
But somewhy it doesn't still work.
I will add some screenshots to post, maybe you can spot the problem from there :)

Comment: @Kevin oh from the screenshot I see you're using deployment target 6.0 try moving up to 7, if not working try 8?

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to drag and drop "GoogleMobileAds.jar" in your Xcode.

2.Then you have to add 2 frameworks(AdSupport,Storekit), and also have to add "GoogleMobileAds" plugin to Build Phase.

For more discriptive steps for integrate AdMob with iOS and Android both, follow the belove link.http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ads-implementation-in-unity-using-admob